# ¿Porque sale null delante de mi array?

Tags: java, array

```
        public static String creaArrayStrings() {
        String ret = "";
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        Short h = 0;

        System.out.println("Introduce el tamaño del array");
        h = Short.parseShort(sc.nextLine());

        String frases[];
        frases = new String[h];

        for (int i = 0; i < frases.length; i++) {
            System.out.println("Introduce la frase " + i);
            frases[i] += sc.nextLine();

        }

        for (int i = 0; i < frases.length; i++) {
            ret += frases[i] + "\t";
        }
            return ret;
    }
```

Con este codigo creo un array con tamaño personalizado para introducir palabra pero cuando lo imprime sale delante de todas las palabras que he introducido null --> array tamaño 2 = nullpalabra1, nullpalabra2. Como puedo quitar ese null

Answer (score 5, accepted):

En esta parte estas agrengando el null,frase[i] en un inicio tiene el valor de null

```
frases[i] += sc.nextLine();
```

el + no debe ir ,estas iterando y agregando no debes sumarle

```
for (int i = 0; i < frases.length; i++) {
            System.out.println("Introduce la frase " + (i+1));
            frases[i] = sc.nextLine();

        }
```